# Как удаленно подключиться к БД postgre на Heroku используя C# и Npgsql?

Tags: c#, postgresql, heroku

Есть БД postgre на Heroku и я удаленно попытался подключиться к ней через написанный на С# клиент, однако программа выдает ошибку **System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure."** и я не понял, как ее исправить. До этого работал только на localhost, на котором все, очевидно, работает как надо. Что делать?

```
internal static string connectionString =
            "Host=1234567.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com;" +
            "Port=5432;" +
            "Database=DB;" +
            "Username=name;" +
            "Password=password;" +
            "Sslmode=Require;";

...
NpgsqlConnection npgSqlConnection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
npgSqlConnection.Open();
...
```

Comment: Так у вас с сертификатом проблемы.  Если самовыпущенный — добавляйте издателя сертификата в систему.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте параметр Trust Server Certificate=true в строке подключения.

#### Например

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста код текстом.